# Entityframeworkcore doesn't release RAM

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to release RAM after my process is complete. When my request is completed RAM doesn't releasing.
For Example: This method selecting byte[] from database and that size is 10MB when I call this method 30 times ram usage increasing 300MB and doesn't releasing.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadExcelReport(int reportId)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = await db.ExcelExportQueue.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.zexlogId == reportId).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (entity == null || entity.zexlogFileBinary == null)
                throw new Exception(Localize("notExcelFileFound").Value);

            await db.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return Ok("");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you are disposing context? Usually who created context should be responsible for Dispose.

Comment: I'm just trying something. I will remove that line but I need to release ram.

Comment: It's not up to you when RAM is released. That's up to the garbage collector. You just need to make sure that you don't keep references to objects that you're no longer using and the system will take care of the rest. Disposing an object has no direct effect on RAM. You should do some reading on the .NET garbage collector.

Comment: Actually I have already read about garbage collector but I don't understand this case because garbage collector should collect this process. This code is very simple as you can see where is the abnormal thing ?

Comment: Simplest explanation is that the GC has not run. Did you use a memory profiler to check memory usage? They usually lets you force a GC,, and should do so if you capture a snapshot.

Comment: Why do you think the garbage collector should have it run? If you have loads of RAM and there is no memory pressure then it simply won't run.

Comment: Ram usage is 98% on my server. When I call this method

Comment: EF Core isn't great for blob storage. I would split the table design and consider using raw sql to read / write streams instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are experiencing memory issues you really need to use a memory profiler to see what is going on. There are several out there but I prefer Jet Brains DotMemory.

https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/

A memory profile will allow you to attach to the process and take snapshots of the memory and dig into the various refences and determine what pieces of code are holding on to references preventing them from being garbage collected.